# Why else if doesnt do anything in this case

Tags: java, if-statement, button, label

I know this might be silly question, but i just started learning few days ago and i was just messing around, and im not sure why this doesnt work, could someone please explain it to me ?

I got a simple window with button and it adds clicks by +1, then after few clicks it multiplies them (that part work) but when it get to "else if" and count * 4 it just doesnt do anything

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    count++;
    label.setText("Number of clicks: " + count);
    if (count > 5){
        label2.setText("Turbo mode activate");
        label.setText("Number of turbo clicks: " + count*2);
    } else if (count > 20){
        label2.setText("SuperTurbo mode activated");
        label.setText("Number of superturbo clicks: " +count*4);
    }

}
```

}

Thank you for answer

Answer (score 1):

because even if the counts gets to 100 it is greater than 5 and then the first code block is always executed and else if never gets the chance.

In your case, you could say that `if (count <= 20)` then do first block or `else { .... }` execute the second block of code.

Comment: @Daniels0n `<= 20` is not equvalent to `> 5` though.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions are evaluated in order. `count > 5` will always be true before `count > 20`: anything greater than 20 is also greater than 5.

You can inverse the conditions to check the more general conditions later and the more specific earlier.

```
if (count > 20) {}
else if (count > 5) {}
```